# How to extract json keys that appear at various levels (dynamic schema)?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I am reading json files into a view.  One of the fields in the view is a json field.  Let's call it `json_col`.
From the json inside `json_col` we want to extract the `text` key value and show it concatenated to the user with `\n`.

*However*, this field can show the `text` key in different "levels" (dynamic schema).
I am successfully achieveing the below parsing `json_col` to text, using `regexp_extract_all` and then `array_join` occurences.

***Using SQL, is there a way to achieve the same result but not parsing the column to text?***

Values displayed to the user:

| id | json_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Header text \n TextL2 \n TextL3 |

JSON value coming in the view:

```
[
    {
        "content": [
            {
                "text": "Header text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": [
            {
                "content": [
                    {
                        "content": [
                            {
                                "text": "TextL2",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "content": [
                    {
                        "content": [
                            {
                                "text": "TextL3",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```